# Why can't I get /comments/new.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, form-for, scaffold

I created models by scaffold command

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable , polymorphic: true
end

...
```

**routes.rb:**

```
 resources :posts, :images, :links do
    resources :comments
 end
```

**comments_controller.rb:**

```
def new
  @comment = Comments.new
end
```

/posts/show.html.erb:

```
 <%= link_to 'Add comment', new_post_comment_path (@post)%>
```

Here I think I need ...(@post, @comment),like from               http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html:

```
<%= link_to 'Ad details', magazine_ad_path(@magazine, @ad) %>
```

but I haven't `@comment` here.

*I get error:*

```
    Showing /home/loza/Projects/my_blog/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

    undefined method `comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f2e4a77c2f0>:0x007f2e4ab23ef8>

Extracted source (around line #1): 
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
```

How need I write so as to get `/comments/new.html.erb`?

Today I've corrected my code:
/posts/show.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'New comment', new_post_comment_path(@post, @post.comments.build) %>
```

/comments_controller.rb:

```
  def new
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new
  end
```

I got the same error again:

```
Showing /home/loza/Projects/my_blog/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fa736859320>:0x007fa73669e238>

xtracted source (around line #1):

  <%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

app/views/comments/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_comments__form_html_erb___1254360398011104975_42800220'
app/views/comments/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_comments_new_html_erb__2117553728149416519_42948680'
```

Where is problem ? How can I solve it?

Comment: `<%= link_to 'Add comment', new_post_comment_path (@post)%>` try to remove space: `<%= link_to 'Add comment', new_post_comment_path(@post)%>`

Comment: The space shouldn't matter, it's nice to have consistent spacing, but the result for this line is the same: `(@post)` becomes `@post` and that's passed to `new_post_comment_path`, the result becomes the second argument for `link_to`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you don't have just `'/comments/new'` path but `form_for(@comment)` is trying to create it.

Your routes are creating path like `'/post/:id/comments/new'` so you have to use `form_for([@post, @comment])`.

Also add `@post = Post.find(params(:is))` in new method or better as before_action callback.

Comment: I had written in posts#new:   I got the same error                                                                                                                                                                                                             @post=Post.find(params[post_id])                                                            @comment =@post.comments.new

Comment: 1. route you want to use is: `posts/:post_id/comments:/new`, so your link should be `link_to 'Add Comment', new_post_comment_path(@post)`. In `commentscontroller#new` you have to find @post, and build new @comment. @post.comments.new or @post.comments.build. you form_for should look like `form_for([@post, @comment])`.

Comment: I've corrected form_for and comments/new and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting, as the error says, is on _comments/*form.html.erb*:

```
form_for(@comment)
```

You need the @post object in there, for `form_for` to figure the right path:

```
form_for([@post, @comment])
```

Comment: Where can I take comment?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant @comment, if there are no comments and you still want to show the form you could do `@comment = @post.comment.build` to build an empty comment for your form to display.

Comment: I had tried  <%= link_to 'Add comment', new_post_comment_path ([@post, @post.comments.build )%> I got error. I cat write this error tomorrow. I forgot commit at work computer

Comment: The add comment link was OK, the error was on your actual form (see my answer: the error is on __comments/form.html.erb_.